# Android: Listing app intents able to use png's

Tags: android

I'd like to get a list of apps on an Android device that are able to use (or to be launched with) PNG's.

I'm using this code:

```
final Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
msg.setType("image/png");
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(msg, 0);
```

But it return zero, which does not reflect reality.
Any other ways of asking the framework about app abilities?

Pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
final Intent msg = new Intent();
msg.setType("image/png");
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(msg, 0);

Log.d("TTT", "Got " + apps.size());
for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); ++i) {
    Log.d("TTT", apps.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString());
}
```